# How Do I Move/Reorder Partitions?

Tags: partitioning

My laptop was originally Windows, I then added an extended partition and installed linux.

I am now reclaiming more of the Windows partition but I have an irritating extra partition in the way.

[image: Partition Table]

I think that `/dev/sda1` is the Windows boot partition (contains files `bootmgr` and `BOOTNXT` etc).

`/dev/sda2` is the Windows partition.

I think `/dev/sda3` is the Windows recovery partition (contains the dir `WindowsRE`).

`/dev/sda4` is clearly the extended partition with linux.

I could move `/dev/sda3` next to `/dev/sda2`, move `/dev/sda4` next to `/dev/sda3` then expand `/dev/sda4`, however, I'd rather have `/dev/sda2` next to `/dev/sda4`.

Is it possible to ***move*** `/dev/sda3` before `/dev/sda2`?

I'm thinking something along the lines of moving `/dev/sda2` into the empty space then using `dd` to to copy `/dev/sda3` into the gap.

I'm not sure about this approach though as I don't know how it affects the partition numbers and grub etc.

Comment: You're not just moving (empty) partitions.  Your partitions each have a filesystem contained within.  In my experience moving a partition/filesystem can take ***many*** hours and cannot be interrupted or canceled.  I just backup the filesystem(s) to another HDD, delete the old partition(s), create the new partition(s) and format to the proper filesystem, and then restore/copy back the files.

Comment: *"/dev/sda4 is clearly the extended partition with linux"* -- That's misleading wording. Partition #4 is an *extended* partition which is the container for *logical* partitions.  An extended partition cannot be formated with a filesystem.  It just so happens that Linux is using all three logical partitions.

Comment: I realise that it can take hours and am happy to just let it run overnight. Whilst backup/restore will work for the stated scenario, for the purpose of this question I'm interested in technical solutions on how to move the partitions (and filesystems within). Your second point about misleading wording is correct, however, I think we understand what I was getting at even if I wasn't explicit.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to move `/dev/sda3` before `/dev/sda2`?

"Moving" the existing `/dev/sda3` so that it is relocated between `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` is possible, but not with just the "move" commands of a partition editor.
You've used up the four MBR partition entries, so any rearrangement of partitions sda1 through sda4 will first require deleting a partition with the loss of its filesystem and files.
So there will have to be a filesystem backup & restore of the deleted partition.

The steps involved are:

1. Backup the filesystem of `/dev/sda3`.
2. Delete `/dev/sda3`.
3. Use a partition editor to "move" (shift) `/dev/sda3` to the right.  (Since only 2/5ths of this partition is used, a time optimization might be possible by first shrinking `/dev/sda3` (on the right side), then shift `/dev/sda3` but leave space on the right, and then expand (on the right side) `/dev/sda3` back to its original size.)
4. Create (and format) a new `/dev/sda3`  in the new unallocated area between `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`.
5. Restore the filesystem of `/dev/sda3`.

---

> I'm thinking something along the lines of moving `/dev/sda2` into the empty space then using `dd` to to copy `/dev/sda3` into the gap.

You cannot simply use commands such as **dd** to relocate a partition.
All of the blocks would be copied, but the partition and its filesystem would still be at its original location because the partition table was not updated.

If you think you really know what you are doing:
The step #2 above should only affect the partition table and not touch the data in the partition.
So in theory the backup & restore could be replaced by modifying step #4 to: create a new `/dev/sda3`, and then **dd** the old partition data (using block addresses of `/dev/sda`) to the new partition.

Comment: I doubt that the suggestion in (3) would actually save time, as shrinking partitions can be very time-consuming with lots of shuffling around - so it also imposes unneccessary wear on the disk

Answer (score 0):

Your disk is partitioned with the MBR scheme. MBR is old and limiting: you can have up to 4 top-level partitions, so if you want to have more, you need to create an "extended partition" which can be partitioned further. But then if you want to move a partition out of extended partition or into it or if you want to extend it outside of extended partition, it becomes a pain in the ass.

If you're going Windows-free, I'd recommend converting your disk to GPT scheme. GPT's partition limit is 128 and you're not going to exhaust it anytime soon :) For Windows if you want to use GPT you also have to boot in UEFI mode, but Linux doesn't have this restriction.

First, **make backups**. [This answer on our sister site](https://askubuntu.com/a/85857) describes how to convert MBR to GPT under Linux (you should do this from a live USB). Focus on the *Convert the disk* part - you don't need the EFI System Partition and GRUB reinstallation because you'll still be booting with the BIOS/CSM method (UEFI boot is awesome though, you could consider it). If everything goes well, you'll be able to boot straight into Linux. If not, the next step is to repair GRUB by using some kind of rescue disk or by chrooting into your local installation if you're familiar with that procedure.

Then you can freely move partitions around because you're not limited to 4 partitions and extended partition boundaries anymore.

If you want to reorder partitions, my preferred method is to create a new one and clone the old one using Clonezilla (or partclone, which is more advanced and low-level, but gives you more control over the process). Note that the new partition can't be smaller than the old one.

I can't stress this enough: **make reliable, restorable backups** before attempting anything. Clonezilla is your friend here too.