# Booted gparted cannot increase size of primary partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted, extension

I need to increase the size of my linux mint partition because it says I have a lack of space (last time I couldn't even boot because of that, I had to delete files and so on).

But my problem is this : when I'm booting from USB stick with gparted, I swapoff the primary partition of 18.63Gb you see on [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U25Fu.png) then try to resize it but I can't INCREASE the size, I can only decrease it.

As you can see I have almost 60Gb of unallocated space because I decreased sdb6's space in order to use this freed space for sdb1. But it didn't work.

How could I add some more space to this linux-swap sdb1 partition ?

(ps: the screenshot was taken on my normal linux session but as I said the problem is related to the situation when I'm booted on live gparted USB).

Comment: You may want to just give up sdb1 (as a swap partition) and just use the space in the extended partition. Otherwise you'll need to resort to LVM or so. What's the big swap for anyway?

Comment: Uhn actually you probably don't need LVM, as you can have multiple swap partitions enabled I think.

Comment: Related question: [How Do I Move/Reorder Partitions?](https://superuser.com/q/1513578/194694)

Answer (score 0):

Your unlocated space is a part of extended partition for now. 
Try these steps-

1. move sdb6 such that unlocated space comes in between sdb5 and sd6
2. move sdb5 so that unlocated space is now in front of sdb5
3. select sdb2 and decrease its size so that unlocated space is out of sdb2 and is after sdb1
4. increase size of sdb1